# Visual C++ 2008 Boost Problem

Tags: c++, boost, multithreading

Hey I'm using the C++ Communication Services Framework, which uses the Boost's Thread library.

I'm compiling one of their test projects (CSF's) and i'm getting a huge errors

The errors are in the Boost Bind library in file **bind/mem_fn_template.hpp**

**EDIT:** I installed Boost through the Boost installers provided by BoostPro

Here are few of the errors

```
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(146) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
        C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(193) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_mfi::mf1<R,T,A1>' being compiled
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(146) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(146) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(146) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(146) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(151) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(151) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(151) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(151) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(151) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(210) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
        C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(243) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_mfi::cmf1<R,T,A1>' being compiled
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(210) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(210) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(210) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(210) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(215) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(215) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(215) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(215) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(215) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(258) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
        C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(305) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_mfi::mf2<R,T,A1,A2>' being compiled
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(258) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(258) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(258) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(258) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(263) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(263) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(263) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(263) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(263) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(320) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
        C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(353) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_mfi::cmf2<R,T,A1,A2>' being compiled
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(320) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(320) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(320) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(320) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(325) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(325) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(325) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(325) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(325) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(368) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
        C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(415) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_mfi::mf3<R,T,A1,A2,A3>' being compiled
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(368) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(368) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(368) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(368) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(373) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(373) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(373) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(373) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(373) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(430) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
        C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(463) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_mfi::cmf3<R,T,A1,A2,A3>' being compiled
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(430) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(430) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(430) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(430) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(435) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(435) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(435) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(435) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(435) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(478) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
        C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(525) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_mfi::mf4<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4>' being compiled
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(478) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(478) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(478) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(478) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(483) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(483) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(483) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(483) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(483) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(540) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
        C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(573) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_mfi::cmf4<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4>' being compiled
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(540) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(540) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(540) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(540) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(545) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(545) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(545) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(545) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(545) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(588) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
        C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(635) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_mfi::mf5<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5>' being compiled
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(588) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(588) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(588) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(588) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(593) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(593) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(593) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(593) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(593) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(650) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
        C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(683) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_mfi::cmf5<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5>' being compiled
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(650) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(650) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(650) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(650) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(655) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(655) : error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(655) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(655) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(655) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(698) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
        C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(745) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_mfi::mf6<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6>' being compiled
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_39\boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(698) : fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

Answer (score 4):

The offending line is

```
template<class U, class B1> R call(U & u, T const *, B1 & b1) const
```

Are you sure you don't have any macro named either `U` or `B1`? You can probably do search over all sources for '#define U' and '#define B1'.

Comment: The obvious is only obvious in retrospect!  I had the same error with a different Boost library, and indeed, elsewhere in my project's code the template parameter token (in a Boost library, though I now see that's irrelevant) had been defined via a macro.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ Communication Services Framework hasn't been updated since 2005, whereas Boost::Thread has been updated frequently since then so it's possible that something's changed that has broken backwards compatibility. I'd suggest trying Boost 1.33 to see if it gives the same errors.